# jQuery selector question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span and an anchor inside a table cell. I have the anchor set up to show a tooltip. I would like the text inside the span to be used for the tooltip. How can I select this text in jQuery?

```
  <td class="row-head" colspan="5"><span class="tip-text">Complete Coverage</span><a href="#" class="help"></a></td>
```

JQuery code - the current selector always finds the first instance only for all tips.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.help').qtip({ style: { name: 'cream', tip: true },
                 content: {
                 text: $(this).find('span.tip-text').html() 
   } });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `$(this)` is being evaluated in the document ready functions context, you can use the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) function to iterate over each `.help`.  The function you are looking for to find the `.tip-text` could easily be [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll) or [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.help').each(function() {
     // iterate over each .help, find its span.tip-text and create the qtip
     $(this).qtip({ 
       style: { name: 'cream', tip: true },
       content: {
         text: $(this).siblings('span.tip-text').html() 
       } 
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your use of `this`.  I recently ran into the same thing where I assumed that `$('some-selector').whatever()` implied a loop over all matching objects.

In fact, it doesn't.  `this` is not referring to the current element with a class of **help**.

If you really need to do something based on the current matching element, you need to use the [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function like this:

```
$('.help').each( function(idx) {
    $(this).qtip({ 
        style: { name: 'cream', tip: true },
        content: { text: $(this).find('span.tip-text').html() } 
    });
});
```

Comment: That each is going to break because you are attaching the qtip to all `.help` again instead of using `$(this).qtip()`

Answer (score 0):

I will confess to having not tested this (yet), but this should fetch the span contents, you can iterate this for each row in your table.

```
$('a.help').siblings('.tip-text').text();
```

Comment: `closest()` won't help as the `.tip-text` is a sibling of the `.help` not a parent.

Comment: Thanks Duncan for the final piece! Thanks to everyone who answered, the iteration was def the key..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.help').qtip({ 
        style: { name: 'cream', tip: true }, 
        content: { text: $(this).parent().find('span.tip-text').text(); }
        }); 
});
```

Although I would just suggest using the anchor's title attribute like so

```
<a href="#" class="help" title='Complete Coverage'></a>
```

and qtip will automatically use that as the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().find('span.tip-text');
```

Find just looks for descendants of the selected element, I think.

http://api.jquery.com/find/